# Slick.js Loading Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, slick.js

I have few slick.js (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) carousels on my page that are displayed within tabs EasyTabs.js (https://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/).

Here is the page with the issue: http://ffb.ca/get-involved/ride-for-sight/#event_locations

Only some of the tabs have "regional sponsors". The sponsor logos usually appear fine on the first (central ontario) tab, but once you click a new tab (northern alberta), the logos stack on top of each other, and then click into place. Sometimes you have to scroll down, or adjust the browser window for the logos to click into place.

It seems like a loading issue or something, but I'm not exactly sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might need to use easytab's 'after' event hook along with the slick 'unslick' method, then (re)initialize the slick instance; so when the user changes tab (the event hook) it tells slick to try start again.

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.easytabs-instance').easytabs().bind('easytabs:after', function() {
        $('.slick-instance').slick('unslick').slick();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect.